# Is there a way to make this lines of code simpler with only one join()-method?

Tags: python, arrays, list

The code itself looks like this:

```
phrase="Don't panic!"
plist=list(phrase)
print(phrase)
print(plist)

phrase_1=''.join(plist[1:3])
phrase_2=''.join(plist[5:3:-1])
phrase_3=''.join(plist[7:5:-1])
phrase=phrase_1+phrase_2+phrase_3
plist=list(phrase)

print(phrase)
print(plist)
```

The result displays as follow:

```
Don't panic!
['D', 'o', 'n', "'", 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c', '!']
on tap
['o', 'n', ' ', 't', 'a', 'p']
```

The main goal is to execute the program with the same result as above with the less lines of code using list slices.

I tried to insert the list slices onto the single variable `phrase=''.join()`

```
phrase=''.join(plist[[1:3],[5:3:-1],[7:5:-1]])
plist=list(phrase)
```

but then it returns a syntax error:

```
    phrase=''.join(plist[[1:3],[5:3:-1],[7:5:-1]])
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any solution to shrink this lines of code?

Comment: Why are you making your string into a list of single characters to begin with? Just use the `phrase` string directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
phrase=''.join((*plist[1:3], *plist[5:3:-1], *plist[7:5:-1]))
```

Where you use unpacking to get all the phrase-parts into a single tuple & then pass that to `''.join()`

This results in the same output:

```
Don't panic!
['D', 'o', 'n', "'", 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'c', '!']
on tap
['o', 'n', ' ', 't', 'a', 'p']
```

Arguably a little hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be converting a string to a list, to multiple lists, each to multiple strings to one string, back to a list.

You can convert the string directly to the target string, and optionally to a list:

```py
phrase = "Don't panic!"

print(phrase[1:3] + phrase[5:3:-1] + phrase[7:5:-1])
print(list(phrase[1:3] + phrase[5:3:-1] + phrase[7:5:-1]))
```

Output:

```
on tap
['o', 'n', ' ', 't', 'a', 'p']
```